# routing and links angular2

Tags: hyperlink, routes, angular

I'm going to be crazy with routing, since angular2 RC1 i cannot route correctly, the last error i have is :

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Component 'LoginForm' does
>   not have route configuration

My code is bellow (i hoppe the usefull parts)

I cannot understand the message of error, what i want is just some links available on my main page using the '[routerLink]' routing to the correct components (my main activities)

Regards

Note : "/app/" is just a base path for my app urls (it does not correspond to a component)

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);


/////////////////////

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <navbartop></navbartop>
    <h1>MAIN APP COMP</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['/app/coursesactivity']">CouresesActivity</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavBarTop],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@Routes([
    { path: '/app/login', component: LoginForm },
    { path: '/app', component: LoginForm }
])

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnActivate {
.....
}

/////////////////////

@Component({
  selector: 'loginform',
  templateUrl: '/app/components/compLoginForm/LoginForm.component.html',
  styles: ['/app/components/compLoginForm/LoginForm.component.css']
})

export class LoginForm implements OnInit {//, OnActivate { 
  constructor(
    //private _router: Router
    //private _routeData: RouteData, deprecated
    //private _routeParams: RouteParams deprecated
    ) {    
  }
...

}
```

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet>` in the template of the `LoginForm`? There is no route configuration for `/app/**courseactivity**`. Where is this `routerLink` supposed to route to?

Comment: no <router-outlet> directive in the LogiForm html page (just a simple page with inputs),  i deleted the route from @Routes for /app/courseactivity to make the code simpler (it will be pushed agin in the future, when the code is ok), the routerLink points to an other component (nothing to do with loginform)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to cleanup the code, i encountered other errors, 
finally i don't know  where the original error came from...
Sorry for thos who helped me.
Regards